# InDesign. Apply updated links from one doc to others?

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, file-management

In InDesign: I originally have 3 documents that uses the same image references and have the same layout, but now the images are updated with different file names and locations.
I have updated one of the 3 documents.

Is there a hack/process/trick to apply the links from the updated document to the other two?

Comment: Are the *file names* really different (and not just the folder)? I can't see how InDesign should be able to guess which image belongs where if the file names have changed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at the very least it would require (operating system *and* application) scripting to find/change images across multiple files.

Comment: @Wolff, some file names have changed name, usually an add of '_cmyk'.

Thanks for questions and thoughts. I guess you are both correct that there is no clean solution for this